# Chrome screen flash when applying a CSS3 animation (only the first time)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css, webkit, css-transforms

*EDIT: The answer from @Archer seems to fix this. (please vote him up, because I don't have enough points to do that).

To learn more about the bug click here: http://www.viget.com/inspire/webkit-transform-kill-the-flash/*

---

My problem is not easy to explain. I have made up a test case on jsfiddle. You can find the link on the bottom of this text.

Before you click on the demo link be aware of the following:

Be sure you are using google chrome. (because of -webkit prefixes in the CSS).

Pay attention the first time you click the orange button. You should see a sort of short flash before the animation starts. When you try again (after clicking on the reset button) everything is ok, no flashing screen. But if you clear your browser cache (CTRL-SHIFT-DEL), close the browser, and reload the page, the hiccup is there again.

I hope i explained it clearly.

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/NKQNX/14/

(sorry for my spelling, english isn't my first language)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, it's a known issue with webkit animations.  A bit of googling came up with this...

```
body {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I added that to the css in your example and tried it about 10 times and didn't get the flicker once, where I was able to consistently get it before.

http://jsfiddle.net/NKQNX/16/

Comment: Could you link to the bug report? It's something I've not heard of as yet, and I'd be intrigued to read more about it. =)

Comment: I just googled it - didn't see any official bug reports.  The above code fixes what is obviously an issue though.

Comment: Here is a blog post about the issue: http://www.viget.com/inspire/webkit-transform-kill-the-flash/

Comment: I just tried your method, well from the post you provided but it didn't work. Yet, adding it to `:before, :after { -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); }` stops the flash for me, incase anyone else comes across this and goes "It doesn't work!"

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this lots of times in older Chrome builds, but as of the last few weeks it has been fixed. I'm running Chrome 19, and don't see these flashes any more.

I think that it happens when a 3d transform is animated. By forcing a 3d translate as Archer has pointed out this is avoided, as the page is already rendered on the graphics card.

Comment: I was using Chrome 19 also, but I did see the flash. <br/>